# Bigcommerce developer workflow

Tags: workflow, webdav, bigcommerce

As the switch to webdav has been made (kinda) we are looking for suggestings and best practice workflows for developing templates on the Bigcommerce platform.

Question: Is there a better webdav workflow than just setting your IDE folder to the mapped drive.

Currently we are using some shortcuts to setup mapped drives such as:

`net use Z: https://store-xxx.mybigcommerce.com/dav /user:username password`

This setups the mapped drive then we would just add these folders to our editors. I know there are better implementations that could involve bash scripts, event listeners on directories, or even post-receive git hooks.

Ideally we interface with a repository as well.

Any suggestions or examples are appreciated.

Comment: In addition to just copy and paste, we have tried individual file CURL statments from shell that DO work, but its entirely arduous to manually copy each file.

Comment: Also tried robocopy but it is clearly much to slow

Comment: I think mapped drive might be the easiest. There are some webdav sync tools that you will find on Github. You can also build a quick and dirty tool using a webdav lib like jsdav (https://github.com/mikedeboer/jsDAV)

Answer (score 1):

When we started developing a theme for BigCommerce the early part was very frustrating since the documentation wasn't that great but with time it's just a breeze. Here is what you should expect and know before you indulge in it

1. Use WebDav to export/import your files under template folders
2. I have tried SmartFtp which works very well with their WebDav (a filezilla kind of experience)
3. Since there is not images folder under blueprint, so you can straightaway upload your theme images folder under template
4. Use %%ASSET_js/yourJS.js%% for custom js or images
5. I have also noticed jQuery conflicts if you directly use $ something withing your template